# Adding Icons to List Preference

Tags: android, listview, spinner, preferences, listpreference

I have a list preference which shows a list of languages of different Countries.

[image]

I'd like to have the flag of each Country shown as well. Can someone please tell me the best way to go about this?

Thank You

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Froyo? ICS is out- why not use its API?

Comment: My mobile is stuck on froyo and I want to test the app with a mobile as well

Comment: Oh, I see. There's always a custom ROM, but ok :]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom alert to show the required list of languages. the custom list can have your custom layout.

Comment: Is there any tutorial which can be helpful?

Comment: What exactly you want then will have few links or sample code